# Error while removing story board in 'swift' project. Error : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have been learning Swift language given that I have decent knowledge of Objective-C. I needed to remove story board from my Swift project. I removed story board file, removed respective plist key, added new view controller with XIB and added following code in Application delegate :

```
var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        if let window = window {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            window.rootViewController = FirstViewController()
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
```

I added single label to my FirstViewController's XIB and also added proper autolayout constraints.

The problem is, I can't see label although the `viewDidLoad` of FirstViewController is being called. Later on, I added `IBOutlet` to label and set its text programatically in `viewDidLoad` by following code:

```
lblHello!.text = "Hello !!!"
```

At this stage, I am getting error :

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

I have cross-checked everything in `File's owner` and other `IBOutlet` stuff. I don't find anything missing.

Please tell me if I am missing anything by my silly mistake. Is there anything additional things that I will have to do for this case?

Comment: for simpler..delete that label and again create an outlet

Comment: @PhillipMills I have checked IB stuff, all are ok..

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER I have deleted label lots of time and re-added, connect IB again. Even I re-added new view controllers many times..

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with `View Controller` and `XIB` connection, because you can see that `viewDidLoad` method is being called but view in not loaded, as I mentioned in the beginning of my question.

Comment: Apple docs say, "it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller".  Do you get any different results doing that?

Comment: @PhillipMills How I would do that ? Can you give me some idea..

Comment: See the "Controller Using Nib Files" section: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my snippet, and it's working

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

And `viewDidLoad()` of `FirstViewController.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var lblTitle:UILabel?

//MARK: - View lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lblTitle!.text = "Hello....!!!"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```